# How to show a spinning icon before a long function call in Webix?

Tags: progress-bar, webix

I have a funtion call which is taking around 10s time to return the result which is then shown into a datatable.

For example, the function takes two JSON object and produces another JSON by processing them. The pseudo code looks like below:

```
var d = longProcessingFunction(jsonObj1, jsonObj2)
$$('mytable').parse(d);
```

I have already used progressbar from https://docs.webix.com/desktop__progress.html#settingprogressbaricon and used it for a url which fetches the data, shows a spinning icon until it fetches and then loads the data into the table.

However, not quite sure how to use it in this context of a plain function call ?

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern is next

```
$$("mytable").showProgress();
webix.delay(function(){
    longProcess();
    $$("mytable").hideProgress();
});
```

webix.delay adds timeout, which is necessary to render progress bar. Still, if longProcess is a sync operation, a browser will stop all repaints and animation while executing the longProcess operation. If you want to have live/animated progress, you need to split longProcess in series of smaller jobs, which can be executed one by one

```
function doChunk(){
    processChunk();
    if (jobDone)
        $$("mytable").hideProgress();
    else
       webix.delay(doChunk);
}
$$("mytable").showProgress();
webix.delay(doChunk);
```

All above is not-webix specific, it is common javascript behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Actually longProcess is a  function  in a custom component (like https://docs.webix.com/desktop__custom_component.html). To explain the problem in simple terms I did not mention that. Now when I call it inside webix.delay (function() { this.longProcess()}) , it gives error asUncaught TypeError: this.longProcess is not a function.